# Gradle replace resource file with WAR plugin

Tags: resources, gradle, war

I'm trying to replace a resource file in my WAR plugin task with Gradle.

Basically I have two resource files:

```
database.properties
database.properties.production
```

What I want to achieve is replace **'database.properties'** with **'database.properties.production'** in the final WAR file under **WEB-INF/classes**.

I tried a lot of things but the most logical to me was the following which does not work:

```
    war {
        webInf {
            from ('src/main/resources') {
                exclude 'database.properties'
                rename('database.properties.production', 'database.properties')
                into 'classes'
            }
        }
    }
```

But this causes all other resource files to be duplicate, including a duplicate database.properties (two different files with same name) and still database.properties.production is in the WAR.

I need a clean solution without duplicates and without database.properties.production in WAR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't make the decision at runtime (which is the recommended best practice for dealing with environment-specific configuration), `eachFile` may be your best bet:

```
war {
    rootSpec.eachFile { details -> 
        if (details.name == "database.properties") {
            details.exclude()
        } else if (details.name == "database.properties.production") {
            details.name = "database.properties"
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Gradle 1.7 adds `filesMatching(pattern) { ... }`, which may perform better than `eachFile`.

Comment: Just tried and it does not work. Looks like it has no effect. :S

Comment: I've updated the code and verified that it works. In a nutshell, changing existing configuration (in this case the configuration done by the `war` plugin) that doesn't fit your needs can be tricky. Sometimes it's better to solve the problem differently. In this case, one alternative would be to delete the "wrong" file (and rename the other) in `processResources.doLast` { ... }. Or you could put the files somewhere other than `src/main/resources` and include them manually as needed (`war.webInf.from ...`). Which solution is best depends on your exact needs (IDE integration etc.).

Comment: It worked. Thanks. The reason that I choose this method is that it required the minimum work. I don't want to keep properties in a separate location. With this method, when I'm working with my IDE, my code sees the test database in database.properties and when I produce my WAR, I know I'm setting the production database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution that works for multiple archive tasks, then you can modify the property files in "build/resources/main" after the processResources task executes. I'm not sure if this is an accepted practice. I work with two archive tasks, jar and par, that are generated from the build folder, so this worked for me.

Also, the following solution uses all files that end in ".production".

I tested this solution with Gradle 1.11

```
classes << {
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: "build/resources/main").include("*.production")
    tree.each { File file ->
        String origName = file.name.substring(0, file.name.length() - ".production".length())
        File orig = new File(file.getParent(), origName)
        orig.delete()
        file.renameTo(orig)
    }
}
```